# Laravel : Order by string date using query builder with MySql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The table have a startDate column which is `VARCHAR` type, so need to get rows by ascending order using this column.

Tried this :

`orderBy(DB::raw("DATE(startDate)"), 'ASC')`

the above does not return correct order, how to pass string date in order by clouse?

Example:

`'startDate' => '07-Nov-2017'`

`$items = DB::table("mytable")->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE(startDate)"), 'ASC')->where('userId','=',$userId)->get();`

Comment: What is `startDate` format?

Comment: Is it Y-m-d? Show a example of `startDate` content.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake with MySQL!

Comment: @Laerte - Yes it is Mysql, I updated my question.

Comment: So, try the answer I posted, and check if it works...

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the date to MySQL format. Try to use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
$items = DB::table("mytable")
           ->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(startDate,'%d-%M-%Y')"), 'ASC')
           ->where('userId','=',$userId)
           ->get();
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - Its mysql.

Comment: @151291 In future please tag your question accordingly

Comment: `ErrorException in Builder.php line 414: Illegal offset type`

Comment: Why modulus here ? %d-%M-%Y

Answer (score 0):

Gunaseelan was right, but with synthax errors, try this :

```
$items = DB::table("mytable")->where('userId','=',$userId)->orderByRaw("DATE_FORMAT('d-m-Y',startDate), ASC")->get();
```

Comment: I tried this but not correct  - 
`"DATE('d-m-Y',startDate), ASC"`
`"DATE(startDate) ASC"`
`"DATE('d-m-Y',strtotime(startDate)), ASC"`
`"DATE(strtotime(startDate)), ASC"`
`"DATE(strtotime(startDate)) ASC"`
`"DATE(strtotime('startDate')) ASC"`